# How to retrieve only specific attributes on Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database which stores users data such as id, points, nickname.. Now I have created a leaderboard where I only need a few (nick, points), right now I use something like this:

```
    DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    Query query = mDatabase.orderByChild("points");
    //initialize Firebase adapter
    ListAdapter adapter = new CustomFirebaseAdapter<User>(this, User.class, R.layout.list_item, query) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, User model, int position) {
            //populate the ListView
```

and then I use getter methods on model.
Now I'm concerned about the security of the code, I think each phone downloads all the data stored inside each user. Is there a way to retrive only the attributes that I need?

Comment: @lello-lelli You are questioning two things: permissions and query a single element. Please change your title to match the question you actually wishes an answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Understand Firebase Realtime Database Rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) at [Google Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/).

You can create resources at [Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) and restrict read and write permissions according to a given user ID that is making the request.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably something like that, I'll look at you links. I missed to say that that outside the leaderboard each user wants to access all its stored data, I just don't want that user A downloads on its device private info about user B for example! Hopefully I can do that

Comment: Then using `$uid` will solve the permission issue. In my case, I allow user to access picture metadata only if the current `$uid` matches the one on each listed resource.

Answer (score 1):

You must to create a ruleset to your users instance.
For example deny read and write to **importantAtributte**:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$importantAtributte": {
        ".read": false,
        ".write": false"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For more information: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data